# Sending HTTP request using URL object but adding headers

Tags: node.js, http, url, request

I have a [URL](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) object and i need to make a request in node.js with the `http` module.

Normally i use:

```
const url = new URL('...');  // from third party module

http.request(url)
```

But I need to add headers to the request.

```
const url = new URL('...');  // from third party module

http.request({
    hostname: url.hostname,
    port: url.port,
    path: url.path,
    method: 'post'
    headers: {...}
});
```

I'm guessing if there's a method to transform the URL object to an option object to avoid using the legacy url.parse (not recommended from documentation itself).

> Note: While the Legacy API has not been deprecated, it is maintained solely for backwards compatibility with existing applications. New application code should use the WHATWG API.

Practically, how to do manually what it's stated in `http.request` arguments documentation:

> If it is a URL object, it will be automatically converted to an ordinary options object.

If I use `Object.assign` with the URL object, it exposes some internal to the final object created and the only solution I found is to manually extract the needed properties...

It's a design flaw or I miss something ?

Comment: do you want to make a post request with form data ?

Comment: did you verify the post request on **postman** first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since node v10.9.0, it's possible to pass url (string or instance of URL) and options arguments separately. Here is the new function signature:

```js
http.request(url[, options][, callback])
```

As for older version, there is no straightforward way to merge URL object and options. Under the hood, Node.js [converts URL object to options object](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/eea5bb4160517f84e9673e685f0b2494214b95de/lib/internal/url.js#L1268) using approach similar to  yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can make all your header info a separate option

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};
```

& pass it to your request like this..

```
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

**Having said that** I would suggest you to use 3rd party npm packages like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to make a get , post request

> Request is a simplified HTTP client comparable to Python’s requests
>   library. This library is much more user friendly than the default http
>   module and has been considered a go-to for the community for several
>   years.

Comment: As stated above I already solved with this same solutions. I fell dubious about the fact `http.request` accepts an argument type which excludes some options and no method to solve other than manually converting this object